# Are there already any Win10 remote exploits?

Tags: windows, exploit

I'm pretty new to pentesting and I just penetrated my first Win7 test-pc several days ago. Now I want to continue with my Windows 10 one.

Does anyone already know some Win10 remote exploits? I heard about eternalsynergy. Are there other ones? I also heard about eternalblue being ported to Win10, but I can't find it anywhere.

What else could I try to penetrate my Win10 PC without user interaction? What are the most common ways and what are more exotic ways?

Comment: Not sure if this question is not too broad. It certainly won't age well, as any list of exploits would have to be updated periodically.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: @PeterHarmann Well... thats kinda true... but otherwise i nearly dont find anything usefull at all. So maybe this question will help all those people who dont find anything too :)

Comment: @TomK. Exploit-DB for example and cvedetails. There are many vulnerabilities. But the problem is that are mostly no released exploits. The only one i found is "EternalSynergy" but this one requires a pipe and even user credentials to work.

Comment: This kind of question is almost like a software recommendation, in that it will get out-of-date really quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question could have been answered with a quick Google search. You can go to [CVE Details](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-32238/Microsoft-Windows-10.html) and find out information about vendors, products, versions, and so on. Most CVEs will post information relevant to a vulnerability, e.g.: "Exploit available." As for "more exotic ways", I think you need to understand exploits, threats, and threat actors in general. Many organizations are compromised via phishing/social engineering primarily, then applications (Office, Excel, IE, etc) are "[client side](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-32238/Microsoft-Windows-10.html)" attacked. (Browser based, file based, etc).

Exploits have been dwindling for some time now, so finding them is increasingly difficult, and threat actors aren't going to burn "[0 day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing))" exploits when they can continue using traditional methods that work time and time again. For what it is worth, metasploit's team does a decent job of adding exploits when there are proof of concepts in the wild/discussed. But you need to also understand that there is a [huge market for exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_for_zero-day_exploits). What this means is that some researchers can hoard their exploits, sell them to heavy hitter buys (govs/mil), or sell them to some exploit clearinghouse. So if you think someone will be making it rain 0 days some time soon, I don't see it happening.